# Retrieving all groups of a user ->Google Directory API

Tags: php, oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm trying to create a page where users within my NGO can login using their GSuite Account. Their group membership is going to determine which parts of the page they can see. When I was younger I used to write my scripts in php, I guess I'm super old school with that nowadays but it's the only thing I can do :D

To retrieve the group memberships I have the following code:

config:

```html
require_once "GoogleAPI/vendor/autoload.php";
$gClient = new Google_Client();
(...)
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly");
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group");
$gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
```

callback-file:

```html
$oAuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
$userData = $oAuth->userinfo_v2_me->get();

$gruppen = new Google_Service_Directory($gClient);
$optParams = array('userKey' => $userData['id']);
$retGruppen = $gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams);
```

$userData returns me the all the data i want about the user. That works quite fine.

The problem is calling the method "listGroups". And I get quite a weird response.

With the account I'm regulary using it works without any problems. I created a test account though - and this account doesn't seem to work at all.

The developers console shows me that I get a code 403 but that's weird cause it still works with one account and it doesn't with the other.

Through various var_dumps i found out that

```html
var_dump($gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams));
```

works for all cases, while it doesn't work anymore in the test account's case as soon as i add the method "->listGroups($optParams)"- but in the regular accounts case it does

Comment: What is the data that you are trying to get? The user's (test account) own list of group? Or you are using the test account to get other user's list of groups?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Exactly. I'm trying to get the user's own list of groups. With some accounts it works, with others it doesnt and I don't know yet where the problem lies. Through various var_dumps I found out that "$gruppen->groups" works out fine in every case, but my test account doesn't call "$gruppen->groups->listGroups($optParams);" while my other account does. The scopes I set are admin.directory.group.readonly, admin.directory.group and admin.directory.user");

Comment: Basically only admins can use that api, so you need to use the creds of an admin to get the info not the calling users creds.

Answer (score 0):

If the OAuth2 you're using it's to authenticate the users you cannot use that Google_Client to check the groups of the user.

You should need to create one app within the Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com), and create a service account on credentials.

After you do that you should login into the Google Admin console (Google Workspace console) and there create a custom role or use a role which has the permission to read groups, on the created/selected role assign the service account as admin.